# When there is Inclusion of Orlicz spaces?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, inclusion-exclusion, orlicz-spaces

It is a classical result that $L^p(\Omega) \subset L^q(\Omega)$ when $q<p$ and $|\Omega| < \infty$. I'd like to know if is there an Orlicz version of this fact. In other words, let $L^{G_1}$ and $L^{G_2}$ Orlicz spaces. When we have $L^{G_1} \subset L^{G_2}?$

It seems that this result holds only (maybe) if the Orlicz spaces $L^{G_1} \subset L^{G_2}$ satisfies the famous $\Delta_2$ and $\nabla_2$ conditions. That is
[image]

If you whant to know more about Orlicz Spaces see the beggining of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602388.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**plug**
Found as Theorem (2.2.3) in the text

*Edgar, G. A.; Sucheston, Louis*, [**Stopping times and directed processes**](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511574740), Encyclopedia of Mathematics and Its Applications. 47. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. xii, 428 p. (1992). [ZBL0779.60032](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0779.60032).

[image: Orlicz]

The reference given there is Chapter II, section 13 of

*Krasnosel’skiĭ, M. A.; Rutitskiĭ, Ya. B.*, Convex functions and Orlicz spaces, Groningen-The Netherlands: P. Noordhoff Ltd. ix, 249 p. (1961). [ZBL0095.09103](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0095.09103).